# How to print The result of just code?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, printing, telerik, justcode

I use [Telerik JustCode](http://www.telerik.com/help/justcode/introduction.html) to facilitate the coding now i use the property `Just Find All Dependent Code` and i get all the results I don't know how to print the results at all !
The print button is disabled in Visual studio .

---

How to get printed document ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, JustCode does not currently support printing of navigation results. I recommend posting it as a feature request on the JustCode feedback portal: http://feedback.telerik.com/Project/100